# How to maintain Webdriver script if UI xpath or other locator changes again and again?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

If we create automation script and again and again path of locator changes then what steps we should follow for again maintain the test script.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bit of a broad question, though it is something that causes all testers issues.

There isn't really a foolproof way to avoid these issues, because html does change as products are developed. You can try and increase your chances of avoiding the issue by using id to locate elements wherever possible, as this is guaranteed to be unique, and isn't susceptible to failing due to layout changes, as XPath is.

If there's no id available then you should move on to more "fragile" locator methods.

See this blog post for reference:

https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/